# Checking for values in a table row in cucumber

Tags: cucumber, assertions

I am trying to check if the value in a data table is correct so what I do is select all the rows and check if that certain tr has_content of the object name and value i am checking for. Problem is, I can't seem to do a `return` in cucumber:

```
Then /^I should see "([^"]*)" beside "([^"]*)"$/ do |value, name|
  all("tr").each do |tr|
    if tr.has_content?(value) && tr.has_content?(name)
      assert true and return
    end
  end
  assert false
end
```

I want something like that. When I find a row that has both the values, then that means it is correct and I should stop the loop and just return true(otherwise it will continue on to the `assert false` in the end)

How do I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well it seems like a dirty hack but I just used a variable to check:

```
Then /^I should see "([^"]*)" beside "([^"]*)"$/ do |value, name|
  has_value_and_name = false
  all("tr").each do |tr|
    if tr.has_content?(value) && tr.has_content?(name)
      has_value_and_name = true
    end
  end
  assert has_value_and_name
end
```

I'm not sure if it will work in all cases...but if you have better solutions please post it too. thanks!

Comment: instead of the old unit testing 'assert'  you should be using the .should method that's part of rspec/cucumber.   See my answer below

Comment: I dont think assert vs should matters at this point as it is a matter of preference :)

Answer (score 0):

Well if it was driving the browser with Watir you could do

```
matchvalue = regex.new(value)
matchname = regex.new(name)

browser.row(:text => matchvalue, :text => matchname).exists?.should = true
```

In your case what about doing

```
Then /^I should see "([^"]*)" beside "([^"]*)"$/ do |value, name|
  result = false
  all("tr").each do |tr|
    if tr.has_content?(value) && tr.has_content?(name)
      result = true
      break
    end
  end
  result.should = true
end
```

Comment: doing a return in a cucumber steps messes up my cukes. it says there shouldn't be a return or something

Comment: "or something" ??   exact error messages would be helpful, if you really want help that is.   I suppose could always omit the return, it will be slower since it has to process all the rows but ought to work otherwise.  And if you are going to use cucumber for results reporting etc, stop using asserts and start using the .should matchers

Comment: sorry i did a work around since mine was dirty so i didn't use it anymore. anyway, i tried to reproduce the error again and here's what i get with the above code: unexpected return (LocalJumpError)

Comment: ah wait..  you should probably be using the 'break' keyword there, instead of 'return'  since you are not really inside a method, that's probably why it doesn't like the return